# "type: module" - Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I decided to move my webpack 5 + babel project from require to es6 modules. I added "type: module" to package.json and changed all require to import in my js files

The code builds successfully in production. However, in dev mode I get a browser error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" because I excluded node_modules for quick build.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Use ESM imports not require?

Comment: Can you post your webpack config? Although at first glance, it seems like you're using webpack for the browser, yet expect to be able to access `node_modules/` in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser environment doesn't have `require` that NodeJS has. *And the latter can't really use `require` anyway for ESM modules.* Your act of excluding `node_modules/` from bundling means that those modules aren't actually present in your builds, thus unusable within the browser.

For optimizing the use of external modules in `node_modules/`, you can look into [cache groups](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/). By default, Webpack 5 should already have a vendor chunk, where all `node_modules/` get bundled together into a chunk, e.g. a separate exported file. This already optimizes external bundles as much as possible, since it can be cached between builds (for Webpack in watch mode, that is).